# Add contacts Windows 10 Universal

Tags: javascript, windows, contacts, uwp

Is it possible to programmatically add contacts to the adress book/ people app in Windows 10 like it is possible in Android?

I have a server on which contact information is stored, and I would like to make an app to synchronise my contacts with Windows 10.

I tried several things, but it didn't really work out. This is how far I've come:

1. Successfully download the contact data.
2. put the contact data in a `Contact` object.

This is what I've tried:

```
                contacts.ContactManager.requestStoreAsync().done(function (contactStore) {
                contactStore.createContactListAsync("name").done(function (contactList) {
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var contact = new contacts.Contact;
                        //populate Contact item
                        contactList.saveContactAsync(contact);
                    }
                    contactList.saveAsync;
                });
            });
```

But I'm getting an *acces denied* error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you have added the contacts capability in app manifest.

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts"/>
  </Capabilities>
```

You will also get the access denied error if you had not request the read/write permission to the contact store.

[ContactStoreAccessType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactstoreaccesstype)

In this case, you can request the “appContactsReadWrite” permission.

But as I tested, there will be some API issues when calling the createContactListAsync method.

The current workaround is adding windows Runtime Component wrapper:

```
public sealed class ContactManagerWrapper
{
    public IAsyncAction AddContactAsync(string userName, string email)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(async (token) =>
        {
            var store = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AppContactsReadWrite);

            var contactLists = await store.FindContactListsAsync();

            var contactList = contactLists.FirstOrDefault();

            var contact = new Contact();

            contact.Name = userName;

            contact.Emails.Add(new ContactEmail() { Address = email, Kind = ContactEmailKind.Personal });

            await contactList.SaveContactAsync(contact);
        });
    }
}
```

WinJS Project:

```
    document.getElementById('click_me').addEventListener("click", function () {
        var mgr = new UWPRuntimeComponent.ContactManagerWrapper();

        mgr.addContactAsync('Jeffrey', 'jeffrey.chen@example.com').done(function () {
            console.log("add contact successfully");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
contacts.ContactManager.requestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AppContactsReadWrite);
```

instead of this

```
contacts.ContactManager.requestStoreAsync()
```

you open the default store and I think its not accessible by developer.

Comment: The other answer contains something similar. Is there a difference? If not, why did you feel the need to post another answer?